# Displaying "Dictionary Averages" Output in Python (version 3)

Tags: python

Let me just start out by asking for your patience in not ranking me badly, I'm trying my best not to sound like a total noob. :)

I'm writing this program for Python to ask the user to enter any number other than -9999 (neg number, a pos number, or zero), and to then give the following Dictionary Average at the end. This is the output I need, for example...

```
Enter a number (-9999 to end):  4
Enter a number (-9999 to end):  -3
Enter a number (-9999 to end): -15
Enter a number (-9999 to end):  0
Enter a number (-9999 to end):  10
Enter a number (-9999 to end):  22
Enter a number (-9999 to end):  -9999

The list of all numbers entered is:
[4, -3, -15, 0, 10, 22]

The dictionary with averages is:
{'AvgPositive': 12.0, 'AvgNonPos': -6.0, 'AvgAllNum': 3.0}
```

So I have the following code, but I'm doing it wrong (clearly) because I don't know how to do it correctly. It's giving me the output "[] None" because I don't know how to output the "dictionary averages" as seen above.

This is what I have:

```
def nums():
    values = []

    while -9999 not in values:
        x = int(input("Enter a numbers (-9999 to end: "))

        values.append(x)
    values.remove(-9999)

    return values

def allNumAvg(values):
    average = 0
    sum = 0
    for n in values:
        sum = sum + n

    average = sum / len(values)

    return average

def posNumAvg(values):
    x = []
    average = 0
    sum = 0

    if int in values > 0:
        x.append(int)

    print(x)

print(posNumAvg(nums()))
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your purpose in making `posNumAvg` so utterly different from `allNumAvg`?!  The latter computes and **returns** something -- so why on Earth do you have the former, instead, **printing** something and returning nothing at all (same as returning `None`)...?!  This asymmetry itself should drive you crazy... **why** do you choose to be so utterly asymmetrical?

That said, there are more bugs per line in `posNumAvg` than I remember seeing recently.  What about starting it again from scratch, leveraging the existing `allNumAvg`, and going e.g

```
def posNumAvg(values):
    return allNumAvg([v for v in values if v>0])
```

...doesn't **this** look better?-)

Now of course you have other problems -- what if none of the values are positive, your existing code would end up trying to divide zero by zero, not a great idea:-).  And, depending on whether you're using Python 2 or 3 (which you don't even bother to mention), `/` might be truncating division or true division -- worth checking.  And several other things, but, I've already suggested fixes for so many of your actual and potential bugs that I'm way over quota for one answer:-).

Comment: Thanks for your help with simplifying it. Any help with the problems you mentioned? The reason I submitted the problem was to find those answers; what do I do if the user enters a neg number, and mostly, how do I get the averages at the bottom as described?

Comment: `if not values: return float('nan')` deals with there not being any values to average -- `nan`, for "not a number", is the float value for "there is no such number".  Prepping the dict is trivial of course: `d={''AvgPositive':posNumAvg(values), ` etc.